# jquery ui datepicker - max date

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have found out that i need to be able to offer a date in the future but it can only be one Sunday ahead of the current date. Right now my code only allows for selecting Sundays and no dates in the future. But I do need to have it so that I could select the upcoming Sunday. Is this possible with the code I have?

```
var fullDate = new Date();
var twoDigitMonth = ((fullDate.getMonth().length+1) === 1)? (fullDate.getMonth()+1) : '0' + (fullDate.getMonth()+1);

$('#startdate').datepicker({
maxDate: twoDigitMonth + "/" + fullDate.getDate() + "/" + fullDate.getFullYear(),
beforeShowDay: disableSpecificWeekDays
});


function disableSpecificWeekDays(date) {
if(date.getDay()==0){
return [true];
}else{
return [false];
}
}
```

Comment: " it can only be one Sunday ahead of the current date" What do you mean by that? If today is the 5th of August, then what are the allowed selectable dates? Only 7th or 7th and 14th or only 14th? Could you please clarify?

Comment: You are right on the target. Today would be Thursday so they could select the 7th, this coming Sunday. Then once the 7th passes the following Sunday is available but next 2 Sundays in the future.